# Displaying "Appendix" in a section inside subappendices environment

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, koma-script, appendices, classicthesis

I am using scrreprt from KOMA packages, the `appendix` package, and the `arsclassica` package.

I'd like to add "Appendix" before the number of an appendix to a chapter.

If I use `scrreprt` and the `appendix` package this can be done. Unfortunately, `arsclassica` package redefines the `\section` command in some way that the `appendix` package cannot add "Appendix" to the title. This also cannot be changed with the `appendixprefix` option of KOMA script.

I found something that almost works (full code at the end):

```
\begin{subappendices}

\begingroup
\def\thesection{Appendix \arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}}

\section{Appendix one}

\section{Appendix two}
\endgroup

\end{subappendices}
```

The only problem is that this way an "Appendix" is added to the name at the ToC, which then is not properly aligned (it runs over the title of the appendix).

My question is then: is there a way to turn off the behavior only for the ToC, while keeping the extra "Appendix" display inside the `subappendices` environment?

Here is the full code that has an issue of not displaying "Appendix" in the title of the section:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside=false,openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
           headinclude=false,footinclude=false,BCOR=12.7mm,DIV=9,%
           numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
           listof=totoc,%
           captions=tableheading]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,listings,%
                eulermath,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Bla}

\begin{subappendices}
\section{Foo}
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`arsclassica` uses `\titleformat` from the `titlesec` package to format sectional units; you can then redefine the section format inside the `subappendices` environment (making the change local) imitating the original definition, but including the appendix name:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside=false,openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
           headinclude=false,footinclude=false,BCOR=12.7mm,DIV=9,%
           numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
           listof=totoc,%
           captions=tableheading]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,listings,%
                eulermath,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Bla}

\begin{subappendices}
\titleformat{\section} 
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}{\spacedlowsmallcaps\appendixname\ %
  {\spacedlowsmallcaps\thesection}}%
  {1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}


\section{Foo}
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Leonardo: you're welcome! Please consider accepting my answer (if you judge it solved your problem).